# SailJs is Deleting Data from pg database

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-postgresql

Something strange is happening with my app, I am using SailsJs with official PostgreSQL driver and my data gets deleted. I don't have any pattern or list of specific events which deletes the data but I have following observations.

- Few days back i was writing a function to destroy data and when I
  executed that function it gave me an error I fixed the error and ran
  my web app again and whoa data from one of my table was all gone.
- Yesterday i wrote a function and I tried to get the HTTP call to that
  function but it was giving me 500 server error, I started debugging it
  and after executing my program 3 to 4 times with this error partial
  data was deleted from one of my database table. Later the error was i
  had a typo in URL.

If any of you guys had any experience with what is happening to me please let me know how to fix it? or at least help me on how to reproduce this issue ?

EDIT

I activated the logs and was waiting for it to happen again and it happened again and here is the log from sailsjs

[image]

[image]

In the logs I saw that its talking about alter.js sync strategy but i have selected it to be the `safe` strategy

[image]

Comment: Do you have any logs either from PG or Sails you can post? So long as they're from your development environment.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski i don't have any logs but I activated logs on my app

Comment: Word of advice, don't show us production logs, if that is where you're logging.

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski thanks for the advice

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski can you look at the logs and help me figure out whats happening here ?

Comment: did you forget to hide the path of your app at the second photo? just in the `sails lift` command

Comment: @luigonsec you've got the hawk eyes lol :p

Comment: I understand that cardimages is a new model and doesn't exist, it created only wheter migrate is equal "alter". when you are in mode developper always used alter for conserved changed.

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me quite a few times, when lifting the app and it is in the process of making changes to the db and it fails, sometimes due to ORM timeout.

What sails do when its lifting and needs to update the data structure is controlled in config/models.js migrate: 'alter', usually commented out, you get a prompt for what to do  1... 2... 3... (writing from the top of my head, i dont remember the actual messages) and a warning about using alter on a production system.

Changing
config/orm.js to have this

```
    // config/orm.js
module.exports.orm = {
    _hookTimeout: 60000 // I used 60 seconds as my new timeout
};
```

And for reasons I don't know changing config/pubsub.js

```
// config/pubsub.js
module.exports.pubsub = {
    _hookTimeout: 60000 // I used 60 seconds as my new timeout
};
```

has helped me, avoid data loss.